# How to find out if "ssh user@server.com" if rsa or ed25519 key is being used if I have both?

Tags: linux, ssh

I have both rsa and ed25519 keys on my local machine as well as on a remote one. I've also added  both local public keys to authorized_hosts file of a remote machine. When I'm connecting to the remote machine via "ssh my_user@server123.com, how do I know whether it's using the rsa or ed25519 key? How can I change that?

Comment: Have you tried `ssh -v MyUser@MyHost`?

Comment: @AlexStragies, how can I force it to use ed25519?

Comment: @Kommi use `-i` for specifying an identity file. It's all in `man ssh`....

Answer (score 1):

> How to find out if “ssh user@server.com” if rsa or ed25519 key is being used if I have both?

Run the client in debug mode. That is, use `-vvv` switches. The output will answer your question.

> how can I force it to use ed25519? – Kommi 3 hours ago

Use the `-i` switch, or the `IdentityFile` option of `ssh_config`. If it will not work and it will still pick up the default identities, use `IdentitiesOnly` option, which will ignore the default identities and use the one you specify.